# Can you Channel Energy while Grappled?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

Can a Cleric (or other character with the Channel Energy class feature) *Channel Energy* while grappled?

I read through the entry, and I did not see anything similar to a spell's concentration check, only the note that the character had to be able to use their Holy Symbol.  Does this prevent Channel Energy while grappled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Channeling energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) is a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-), which means it cannot be disrupted by enemies, and it has one physical requirement:

> A cleric must be able to present her holy symbol to use this ability.

Then checking the [grappling section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) of the CRB:

> Instead of attempting to break or reverse the grapple, you can take any action that doesn’t require two hands to perform ..

So as long as the cleric in question isn't using a cinder block or similar for her holy symbol, and assuming she doesn't keep the symbol at the bottom of her backpack, she should be fine to channel while grappled.  (Not at all true for the [pinned condition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned), however.)

Comment: Could a cleric conceivably have their holy symbol attached to their breastplate, for example, so that they can "present" it even while pinned?

Comment: Given that the pinned text states both that you "cannot move" and only allows mental and verbal "actions", I think it'd be a stretch to allow someone to "present" something in such a condition, as presentation usually implies physical behavior (one can imagine the cleric in your example thrusting his chest out or something - counting it as being *presented* simply by virtue of being visible at all times seems to miss the spirit of the rule).  Having said that, I don't know of anything in RAW that makes it explicit either way.

Comment: As a GM I certainly wouldn't allow it while pinned, but *Black Tentacles* can't pin at any rate, which was the situation in my game last week.

Comment: Yeah, if you're hogtied on the floor you're not really going to be able to present something on your breastplate.  Unless you're real lucky and spend an action point or harrow point or whatever if your campaign supports it!  But I agree, grappled yes, pinned no.